# Arabic custom actions with google assistant?

Tags: action, arabic, custom-action, google-home, google-assistant

I want to create arabic custom actions with google assistant but when I try to change language settings from english to arabic in the developer action console I can't find Arabic, and the users will then be able to interact with your actions in the selected languages! Does anyone has an idea? is it possible to create arabic google actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this documentation about languages and locals for google actions https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/languages-locales it doesn't contain arabic language, I think it's not available for the moment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).